# React state not updating after function call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, reducers

I'm trying to update my react state before making changes but it is not updating. Changing state is async but I cannot figure out how to make update the state inside my context in the code example below:

```
const initialState = {
    user: null
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const updateUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('currentUser')
    //res.data.user is the user stored in the database
    dispatch({ type: SET_USER, payload: res.data.user })
}

const getUser = async () => {
    try {
        await updateUser()
        if(state.user) {
            console.log('User is not null')
        } else {
            console.log('User is null')
        }
    } catch (err) {
        //Handle error
    }

}
```

Here is the reducer:

```
export default (state, action) => {
    { ... }
    case SET_USER: return { ...state, user: action.payload }
    { ... }
}
```

I am calling the `getUser` function inside my component with the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUser()
}, [])
```

This code example always returns `User is null` because the state is not updated when calling the `updateUser` function.

Note: This is a simple version of the context and the reducer

Comment: This might a silly question but have you checked `res.data.user` ? Also, it would be better if you post the full code before we can make any deductions

Comment: Yes res.data.user returns me the user stored in the database. The object is not empty. This is everything related to these two functions, the rest is not related to the user itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for the fetch but not for the state to be updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUser()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if(state.user) {
        console.log('User is not null')
    } else {
        console.log('User is null')
    }
}, [state.user])
```